# Action of the Haar measure on the Heisenberg group

Tags: integration, haar-measure, heisenberg-groups

The Heisenberg group is $\mathbb{H}^N=\mathbb{R}^{2N+1} = \left\{ (x,y, \tau )   \right\}\in \mathbb{R}^N \times \mathbb{R}^N \times \mathbb{R}$ equipped with the group operation

\begin{equation}
    (x,y, \tau ) \circ (\tilde{x}, \tilde{y}, \tilde{ \tau } ) = (x+ \tilde{x}, y+\tilde{y}, \tau +\tilde{ \tau } + 2  \left( x \cdot \tilde{y} - \tilde{x} \cdot y\right))
\end{equation}

I have a question which is the following. Some materials I'm studying say without much detail that the Haar measure $d\eta$ in $\mathbb{H}^N$ is "similar" to the Lebesgue measure $dxdyd\tau$ in $\mathbb{R}^{2N+1}$. However, I don't know if when they say similar they coincide in any measurable Borel set. For example, if $f(x,y, \tau )=a(x)b(y)c(\tau)$ has separable variables with $a, b, c$ functions Lebesgue integrable, I don't know if I can solve $\int_{D} f(\eta)d\eta$ (where $D$ is a ball in the Heisenberg group for example) it in the same way as in $\mathbb{R}^N$, separating into three integrals depending on $x$, $y$ and $\tau$ or if I can estimate above or below by exchanging Haar's measure for Lebesgue's measure. Thank you in advance if anyone can clarify this question for me.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "solving". The Haar measure on the Heisenberg group is not a product measure, so I don't see the relation to the Fubini argument here. Obviously you can disintegrate over say vertical torus and get integral over the horizontal torus - the abelization of the Heisenberg group, which is isomorphic to R^2, where you may use the integration formula you know.

Comment: I believe they use similarity as in share the main property of the Haar measure, namely invariance under translations (and in this case, bi-invariance due to unimodularity).

Comment: @Asaf but do the integrals with respect to the Haar measure have no relation to the integral of the Lebesgue measure? For example, $\int_D f(\eta) d\eta \leq C \int_D f(x,y, \tau)dxdyd\tau$ ou $\geq$?

Comment: What do you mean by that? The Heisenberg group is not isomorphic to $R^{3}$ (for example, it is not commutative). What are the relations between $\eta$ and $x,y,\tau$ in your notations? How do you even define $f$? Are you defining it over some Lie algebra?

Comment: @Asaf $\eta = (x,y,\tau)$. $D$ is a set in the Heisenberg group (therefore it is also a set of Euclidean space), a ball for example. Imagine that $f$ can be written as the product of three functions, one in each variable f(x,y,\tau) = a(x)b(y)c(\tau). I just want to know that if the integral with respect to the Haar measure (left side) relates in some way to the integral with respect to the Lebesgue measure (right side).

Comment: What do you mean $D$ is a subset of the Euclidean space? which Euclidean space. How would you write such $f$ that should be defined all over $H$ and still be interesting (say Lipschitz)? I also don’t get what is “the Lebesgue measure”, there is no Lebesgue measure on $H$, rather than a Haar measure. Your question doesn’t make any kind of sense.

Comment: I think the question makes perfectly good sense.  The definition given by OP identifies $H^N$ with $\mathbb{R}^{2N+1}$ in a commonly used, and fairly natural, fashion.  Of course this identification is not a group isomorphism, but it is a diffeomorphism.  And under this identification, the Haar measure on $H$ coincides exactly with the Lebesgue on $\mathbb{R}^{2n+1}$, up to a constant scaling of course.

Comment: @Asaf: You can view $(x, y, \tau)$ as simply a particular coordinate chart on $H^N$, if you like.  Then the claim is that Haar measure, when written in these coordinates, is Lebesgue measure.  The $\eta$ is just the dummy variable in an integral, and calling the Haar measure $d\eta$ is a slight abuse of notation, but whose meaning I think is quite clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure why they would use the word "similar".  With $H^N$ identified with $\mathbb{R}^{2N+1}$ as you defined it, Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^{2N+1}$ literally **is** the Haar measure on $H^N$ (up to a constant scaling, of course).  Therefore, any method you might use to compute an integral with respect to Lebesgue measure, is certainly just as valid for the integral with respect to Haar measure, since they are precisely the same thing.

One way to verify this is to write down the map $g \mapsto h \circ g$ in the coordinates you gave, and compute its Jacobian, which is easily seen to be a triangular matrix with $1$s on the diagonal.  So its Jacobian is 1, which means it preserves Lebesgue measure.  Since $h$ was arbitrary, we have shown that Lebesgue measure is a left-invariant measure on $H$, so it is a Haar measure.  And we know from general theory that Haar measure is unique up to scaling.

If you want a more intrinsic statement, you can note that since $H^N$ is nilpotent, connected, and simply connected, the exponential map $\exp : \mathfrak{h}^N \to H^N$ is a diffeomorphism.  Since $\mathfrak{h}^N$ is a finite-dimensional vector space, it admits Lebesgue measure $m$, i.e. a nontrivial translation-invariant measure, unique up to scaling.  Now we look at the pushforward of $m$ under $\exp$, and using the Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff-Dynkin formula, we can verify much as before that this measure on $H^N$ is invariant under left (and right) translation.

Comment: I am extremely grateful for your attention! I got it, that was exactly what I wanted to know about. Another question, are the measures the same only in the entire $H^N$, or are they also the same in any measurable subset?

Comment: Because you identified $H^N$ with $R^{2N+2}$ to conclude that the measures are the same unless constant, so if I have a measurable set in $H^N$ I can identify it with some measurable set in $R^{ 2N+2}$? I cited the ball for example, because I know that the ball in the Heisenberg group is included in a ball in the Euclidean space $R^{2N+2}$, just by rescaling the radius of the ball. So I would like to know if when I have an integral with respect to the Haar measure on a ball of $H^N$, can I relate it to an integral with respect to the Lebesgue measure on some ball of $R^{2N+2}$?